# Click on built-in menu button on Samsung devices when my app is opened sounds twice

Tags: java, android, audio, menu

Click on built-in menu button on Samsung devices when my app is opened sounds twice (when sounds of clicks on the devices are enabled).
That's my menu file main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:title="@string/settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

That's how I inflate it in Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

I've noticed, that the behaviour of this button on other apps is normal, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'` instead latest in your project dependencies. [read more](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=159789)

Comment: It seems to be the only workaround for now, but I don't think it's worth it in my app. Anyway, thanks for help.